# PtrToStructure() generates SafeArrayTypeMismatchException

Tags: exception, interop

Folks,

Please help me chase out a `SafeArrayTypeMismatchException` that I'm getting. I need to pass a `struct` to unmanaged DLL. One of the `struct` members is a variable-length array. Unmanaged code will populate it with data, then my C# code will use the data.

My approach is this:

1. Get `IntPtr` for my structure using `StructureToPtr()`, do the memory allocation too, of course.
2. Call unmanaged function, and pass `IntPtr` as a parameter
3. Get the populated structure using `PtrToStructure()`

If for the purposes of an exercise I call `StructureToPtr()` and `PtrToStructure()` back-to-back there are no exceptions.

`PtrToStructure()` generates `SafeArrayTypeMismatchException`, if I put a call to unmanaged DLL between `StructureToPtr()` and `PtrToStructure()`. The description for `SafeArrayTypeMismatchException` is "Mismatch has occurred between the runtime type of the array and the sub type recorded in the metadata."

Any suggestion or insight is really appreciated!

I can post my code if needed.

- Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET marshaller can't handle C/C++ arrays of unknown size.  An array in .NET always has a fixed size associated with it but C/C++ arrays are just a pointer to a memory block.  The marshaller has no way to know how large the array returning from the C/C++ code is, so it throws an exception.

What it's is trying to do in your case is to marshal the array as a SafeArray which is a COM type - an array that contains it's own size, but you're array isn't a SafeArray.

There isn't a way to get the marshaller to handle this automatically.  Declare the struct member you are using as an IntPtr and manually create  .NET array and copy the values in.  See [this for an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2009/02/18/marshalling-complicated-structures-using-pinvoke.aspx) of how to do that.

Comment: Perhaps, your paragraph about SafeArray have pointed me in a right direction.  After some groping, I have changed the array to a string with [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)].  I seem to be receiving valid data from the call to unmanaged DLL.